# AngularJS ngmap passing scope variable to infoWindow

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, infowindow

i am using ngmaps (https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps) to dynamically load markers and infoWindows in my application.

in my view it looks like this:

```
<marker
    data-ng-repeat="ltd in ltds"
    data-position="{{ltd.gps}}"
    data-title="{{ltd.code}}"
    data-draggable="false"
    data-visible="true"
    data-icon="images/marker.png"
    data-on-click="showInfoWindow(event, ltd.code)">
</marker>

<info-window data-ng-repeat="ltd in ltds" id="{{ltd.code}}" data-position="{{ltd.gps}}" data-ltd="{{ltd}}">
    <div ng-non-bindable>
        <div class="infoWindow">
            <div class="content">code: {{ltd.code}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</info-window>
```

But in the infoWindow content {{ltd.code}} is not shown. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

The solution above didn't worked for me, I think it has something about the ng map version

So I wrote my on solution:
http://plnkr.co/edit/eEE9tX4PlDstCeiQI6x2?p=preview

```js
     $scope.showInfoWindow = function (event, p) {
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var center = new google.maps.LatLng(p[0],p[1]);

        infowindow.setContent(
            '<h3>' + p + '</h3>');

        infowindow.setPosition(center);
        infowindow.open($scope.objMapa);
     };`
```

I create the info window on a click event, then I have full control of the info window

Answer (score 2):

remove the `ng-non-bindable` directive from your div

from documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngNonBindable:

> The ngNonBindable directive tells Angular not to compile or bind the
>   contents of the current DOM element. This is useful if the element
>   contains what appears to be Angular directives and bindings but which
>   should be ignored by Angular. This could be the case if you have a
>   site that displays snippets of code, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

I found this way:

Template:

```
<marker ng-repeat="marker in markers" position="{{marker.location.latitude}}, {{marker.location.longitude}}" on-click="showDetails(event, marker.id)"></marker>
              <info-window id="details">
                <div ng-non-bindable="">
                  <h4>Aja {{ecopoint.name}}</h1>
                  <p>{{ecopoint.details}}</p>
                  <a ng-click="next(ecopoint)" translate>Seleccionar</a>
                </div>
              </info-window>
```

Controller:

```
    $scope.showDetails = function(evt, id) {

    var ecopointSearch = $filter('filter')($scope.markers, { id: id });

    $scope.ecopoint = ecopointSearch[0];

    $scope.showInfoWindow.apply(this, [evt, 'details']);
  };
```

Comment: I feel like this is somehow cheating, but damned if it doesn't work perfectly compared to the other examples